# Element not clickable in responsive mode

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project with React but I am experiencing this wield issue whenever my application is in responsive mode the element will not be clickable.

**A few notes**
The element z-index position is set to a high value[image]

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: Maybe your element has a pointer-events property set to "none", which would prevent it from being clickable?

Comment: no it doesn't have.

Comment: Well, without any code, we could only speculate. Check if there are any other event listeners or handlers that may be preventing the click event from firing.